# UICollectionViewLayout supplementary view duplicate on delete

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionviewlayout

I have been tinkering with a UICollectionViewLayout for a few days now, and seem to be stuck on getting a Supplementary view to delete with animation using the `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`

I have finally made some headway and discovered this issue. Initially it looked as if it was not animating, because i was not getting a fading animation. so i added a transform on it to get it to rotate... and discovered a supplementary view is in fact being animated, but another one just sits there. until its finished and the unceremoniously disappears not being affected by being told to disappear at all. So to sum up it looks like an exact copy is made and that is animated out for `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` and the original just sits there unmoving and animating, then both disappear.

This copy or whatever it is does not disappear either until i scroll the view.

Does anyone have any insight into this issue?

## Update

So after some tweaking, experimentation and many hypothesis later as to what was causing the issue, it turns out that the culprit was this method

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsToDeleteForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind
{
    NSMutableArray *deletedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    
    [self.updatedItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UICollectionViewUpdateItem *updateItem, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop)
     {
         switch (updateItem.updateAction)
         {
             case UICollectionUpdateActionInsert:
             {
                 if (_unReadHeaderIndexPath != nil && [self.layoutInformation[ChatroomLayoutElementKindUnreadHeader] count] == 0)
                 {
                     [deletedIndexPaths addObject:_unReadHeaderIndexPath];
                     _unReadHeaderIndexPath = nil;
                 }
                 
             }
                 break;
                 
             case UICollectionUpdateActionDelete:
             {
                 [deletedIndexPaths addObject:updateItem.indexPathBeforeUpdate];
             }
                 break;

             default:
                 break;
         }
     }];
    
    return deletedIndexPaths;
}
```

The part to focus on is here

```
if (_unReadHeaderIndexPath != nil && [self.layoutInformation[ChatroomLayoutElementKindUnreadHeader] count] == 0)
{
    [deletedIndexPaths addObject:_unReadHeaderIndexPath];
    _unReadHeaderIndexPath = nil;
}
```

Particularly the `_unReadHeaderIndexPath = nil;`

What this is doing is making a supplementary view disappear which indicates unread messages when the user inserts any text and then setting it to nil so it is not added multiple times, the logic is sound however the method in which is employed seems to be the issue.

`indexPathsToDeleteForSupplementaryViewOfKind:` is called multiple times and one can assume it needs multiple passes through it to work properly but since we nil `_unReadHeaderIndexPath;` it seems like it isn't added to the returned array at the appropriate time.

It also seems like the incorrect method in as I'm checking for insertion action in a method name `indexPathsToDeleteForSupplementaryViewOfKind:` so the solution was to move all of that logic to the method

`prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:`

Where we originally set the values for `self.updatedItems` in the first place. Which means i can get rid of that member variable altogether. And it animates and disappears without any odd copy sticking around.

Comment: You'll need to provide the minimum part of your code that exhibits this issue. That most probably includes your `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` as well as your update calls.

Comment: Apologies @jcaron, was busy over the weekend, will update the question with relevant info now

Comment: Same here, seen this issue!